# How long is a azure subscription consent (in Azure AD) valid for? Does it have to be renewed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When we login and using admin consent. How long is a subscription consent valid for?  Does it have to be renewed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consent in Azure Active Directory is valid until it is [explicitly revoked](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/revoking-consent-azure-active-directory-applications/).

Do note though that there is an `expiryTime` property on the [OAuth2PermissionGrant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#oauth2permissiongrant-entity), however it is not implemented yet.

> **expiryTime**
>
> *Edm.DateTime POST, GET, PATCH*
>
> Reserved. Returns null. Do not use.